# PHP: foreach multidimensional get all arrays

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

Basically i have this array structure and i cannot find any possible way to display all the product_id in a foreach loop
This is the array structure

```
    $params['mmmmm'] = $get_products;
    [mmmmm] => Array
    (
        [76] => Array
            (
                [id_shop] => 1
                [product_id] => 4
            )

        [77] => Array
            (
                [id_shop] => 1
                [product_id] => 5

            )

        [78] => Array
            (
                [id_shop] => 1
                [product_id] => 6
            )

    )
```

if I do

```
foreach ($params['mmmmm'] as $product) {
  echo $product['product_id']
}
```

I only get:

```
4
```

Somehow I fail to loop through all of them. 
Please help!

Comment: What do you see if you add a `var_dump($product)` after (or in place of) your `echo $product['product_id']`?

Comment: it's really hard to do this since i'm working in prestashop and logging everything in a file. In any case - it's just prestashop weird. You have to pull 78 classes to get some basic details about a order.

Comment: add `var_dump($get_products);` at the very top of your code to see that the array given to the variable is full of more than one row?

Answer (score 1):

Given your example you need to add a `;` at the end of the echo, but the code should work as expected and output `456`. If it doesn't then the error is in something you've not shown on the question, can you show the complete foreach loop and show what a `var_dump($product);` at the top of the foreach loop says?